# ForEach Bulk Post Requests are failing

Tags: node.js, foreach, request-promise

I have this script where I'm taking a large dataset and calling a remote api, using request-promise, using a post method.   If I do this individually, the request works just fine.  However, if I loop through a sample set of 200-records using forEach and async/await, only about 6-15 of the requests come back with a status of 200, the others are returning with a 500 error.

I've worked with the owner of the API, and their logs only show the 200-requests.  So I don't think node is actually sending out the ones that come back as 500.

Has anyone run into this, and/or know how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's no code in node.js that automatically makes a 500 http response for you.  Those 500 responses are apparently coming from the target server's network.  You could look at a network trace on your server machine to see for sure.

If they are not in the target server logs, then it's probably coming from some defense mechanism deployed in front of their server to stop misuse or overuse of their server (such as rate limiting from one source) and/or to protect its ability to respond to a meaningful number of requests (proxy, firewall, load balancer, etc...).  It could even be part of a configuration in the hosting facility.

You will likely need to find out how many simultaneous requests the target server will accept without error and then modify your code to never send more than that number of requests at once.  They could also be measuring requests/sec to it might not only be an in-flight count, but could be the rate at which requests are sent.

Comment: I thought that as well.   But the interesting thing is I can use PostMan to submit the same request 200-times, with no issue.

Comment: I'm just curious if there's a chance that my node service is timing out the request if there are too many in queue?

Comment: @TheJason - As far as I know, there's no limit on the queue size.  Further, it would just fail the http request, not issue a 500 response which signifies a successful connection to the target that returned a 500 response.

Comment: @TheJason - When you do it from Postman, is it doing them one after the other or 200 requests at a time, all in flight at the same time?

Comment: @TheJason when you do it from postman, and when you do it from node, are they both done on the same machine? also, It is possible that there's a proxy or reverse-proxy in between? perhaps it has a rule about certain clients/user agents, and perhaps that proxy has a bug in the rule's implementation...

Comment: Like Root pointed out check the reverseproxy logs, if they have nginx or HAP sitting on top of it then those access logs are pretty useful in real time to assess the problem. 500 in general would be server crash or inability to serve the request.